# Search Magento from HTML5 desktop app

Tags: magento-1.6, search

I need some pointers on where to look/what to read etc in order to understand how to go about building a desktop app that can search my magento store.

I have a rough idea of how this could work, but perhaps there are better methods/ways of doing this that I do not know about.

If anyone has info they could point me at, or any pre-built starting points that I could take onwards to develop, that would be great!

I need to figure out how to get the search results from Magento for this purpose. I imagine it will use the Magento API, but beyond a very limited and basic understanding here, I could use some guidance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would extend the magento SOAP API for a search API and then call this with the terms and show them.

Described here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

I hope, I copy the important parts... Never used the API.

```
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <customer translate="title" module="customer">
                <model>customer/api</model> <!-- our model -->
                <title>Customer Resource</title>
                <acl>customer</acl>
                <methods>
                    <list translate="title" module="customer">
                        <title>Retrive customers</title>
                        <method>items</method> <!-- we have another method name inside our resource -->
                        <acl>customer/list</acl>
                    </list>
                    ....
                </methods>
                ....
        </resources>
        ....
    </api>
</config>


<?php
class Mage_Customer_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
    public function create($customerData)
    {
        try {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setData($customerData)
                ->save();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
            // We cannot know all the possible exceptions,
            // so let's try to catch the ones that extend Mage_Core_Exception
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $customer->getId();
    }
}


<?php
class Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Customxmlrpc
    extends Varien_Object
    implements Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Interface
{
    /**
     * XmlRpc Server
     *
     * @var Zend_XmlRpc_Server
     */
    protected $_xmlRpc = null;

    /**
     * Set handler class name for webservice
     *
     * @param string $handler
     *
     * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Xmlrpc
     */
    public function setHandler($handler)
    {
        $this->setData('handler', $handler);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrive handler class name for webservice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHandler()
    {
        return $this->getData('handler');
    }

    /**
     * Set webservice api controller
     *
     * @param Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller
     *
     * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Xmlrpc
     */
    public function setController(Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller)
    {
        $this->setData('controller', $controller);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrive webservice api controller
     *
     * @return Mage_Api_Controller_Action
     */
    public function getController()
    {
        return $this->getData('controller');
    }

    /**
     * Run webservice
     *
     * @param Mage_Api_Controller_Action $controller
     *
     * @return Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Xmlrpc
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->_xmlRpc = new Zend_XmlRpc_Server();
        $this->_xmlRpc->setClass($this->getHandler());
        $this->getController()->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
            ->setBody($this->_xmlRpc->handle());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch webservice fault
     *
     * @param int    $code
     * @param string $message
     */
    public function fault($code, $message)
    {
        throw new Zend_XmlRpc_Server_Exception($message, $code);
    }
} // Class Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Customxmlrpc End
```

Comment: Would you have any pointers or links to info to show me what you mean, and/or how to do this sort of thing?